# How to install endnote x8 into Microsoft word 2016/2017

Tags: macos, ms-office

I have installed endnote x8 onto my mac (macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.3). Microsoft word was already installed and I cannot seem to link them together.

I have tried to install it through endnote -

1. Endnote X8 - Customizer
2. click "cite while you write box"

It then comes up and says "The customizer could not find Microsoft Word 2008, 2011 nor 2016 installed on this computer. 
If you have installed Microsoft Word to any non-standard paths, or have changed the start-up file location, please click the customize button"

When I click this a table comes up with Version, Word Path & Startup File location. There is a little plus button which I clicked that comes up with all my documents. I tried selecting Microsoft Word but it says "the item you picked does not seem to be in a Microsoft Word installation directory"

Does endnote x8 work with Word 2016 for Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Endnote x8 isn't always compatible with Word 2016.

Word had a major upgrade behind the scenes - the older version of endnote works with Word version 15.x and lower. A newer patched (fixed) version of endnote x8 works with Word version 16.x (and possibly back with some older Word, too).

I would update both Word to the latest version and endnote to the latest version and try the install again.

Details are here from the endnote vendor support:

https://support.clarivate.com/Endnote/s/article/EndNote-Word-2016-Mac-version-16-Compatibility?language=en_US